# How to bind a Polymorphic Properties of a Models in .NET core

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

I have an ASP.NET Core Web API end point which takes (FromBody) The Search object defined below

```cs
public class Search {
    public int PageSize {get;set;}
    public Expression Query{get;set;}
}
    
public class Expression {
    public string Type {get;set;}
}
    
public class AndExpression {
    public IList<Expression> Expressions {get;set;}
}
    
public class MatchesExpression {
    public string FieldId {get;set;}
    public string Value {get;set;}
    public string Operator {get;set;}
}
```

So... if I post the following JSON to my endpoint

```
{ 
  "pageSize": 10, 
  "query": { 
    "fieldId": "body", 
    "value": "cake", 
    "operator": "matches"
  }
}
```

I successfully get a Search Object, but the Query property is of type Expression, not MatchesExpression.

This is clearly a polymorphic issue.

This article (towards the end) gives a good example of a how to deal with this issue when your entire model is polymorphic.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/advanced/custom-model-binding?view=aspnetcore-5.0

In my case, the property of my Model "Query" is polymorphic, so Im unsure how to build a ModelBinder for my Search object that will allow me to handle the Query Property

I Imagine, I need to write a model binder to construct the search object and then follow the pattern described for the property, however I cannot locate any examples of how to implement a model binder that isnt utterly trivial.

Any suggestions on how to achieve this? Good sources of information?

Comment: It may be that you just need to write a model binder for the Expression type, and the system will use it for the Query property, and revert to the default binder for the other properties to construct the final Search instance. I'm not sure, but an easy way to check it is to provide a dummy/empty implementation, put a breakpoint in there, and see if it gets hit. If it does, implement the rest.

Comment: Im using the [FromBody] attribute which apparently prevents the ModelBInding from working in properties attributes https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/4553 or by using ModelBinderProviders :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So.. I gave up with ModelBInders (because Im using the FromBody attribute which isnt compatible with my aims).

Instead I wrote a System.Text.Json JsonConvertor to handle the polymorphism (see shonky code below)

```
using Searchy.Models;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text.Json;
using System.Text.Json.Serialization;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Searchy
{

    public class ExpressionJsonConverter : JsonConverter<Expression>
    {
        public override Expression Read(ref Utf8JsonReader reader, Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options)
        {

            Utf8JsonReader readerClone = reader;

            using (var jsonDocument = JsonDocument.ParseValue(ref readerClone)) 
            { 
                if (!jsonDocument.RootElement.TryGetProperty("type", out var typeProperty))
                 {
                 throw new JsonException();
                }

                switch (typeProperty.GetString()) 
                {
                    case "comparison":
                        return JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Comparison>(ref reader, options);
                    case "and":
                        return JsonSerializer.Deserialize<And>(ref reader, options);
                }
            }

            return null;
        }

        public override void Write(
            Utf8JsonWriter writer,
            Expression expression,
            JsonSerializerOptions options)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

My Expression class also had the following attribue

```
[JsonConverter(typeof(ExpressionJsonConverter))]
```

Comment: I can't vote this up enough! All that documentation from Microsoft, and I didn't see anything about it not working with `FromBody` - I lost two days trying to figure out why my custom ModelBinder and ModelBinderProvider wasn't working. They also didn't mention that it doesn't work with `application/json` either, only seems to work with form submission.

Answer (score 0):

I recently ran into the same issue, but was using Newtonsoft.Json, here is iasksillyquestions' solution using Newtonsoft.Json:

```
public class ConnectionJsonConverter : JsonConverter<Connection>
    {
        public override Connection? ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, Connection? existingValue, bool hasExistingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
        {
            // if this is the base type, deserialize it into the child type
            if (objectType == typeof(Connection))
            {
                JObject parsedObject = JObject.Load(reader);

                if (!parsedObject.TryGetValue("connectionType", out var connectionType))
                {
                    throw new Exception("Unable to parse ConnectionType");
                }

                switch (connectionType.ToObject<ConnectionType>())
                {
                    case ConnectionType.Database:
                        return parsedObject.ToObject<DatabaseConnection>();
                    case ConnectionType.LDAP:
                        return parsedObject.ToObject<LDAPConnection>();
                    default:
                        throw new Exception("Unrecognised ConnectionType");
                }
            }

            // if it is a child type, just deserialize it normally
            else
            {
                serializer.ContractResolver.ResolveContract(objectType).Converter = null;
                return serializer.Deserialize(reader, objectType) as Connection;
            }
        }

        public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, Connection? value, JsonSerializer serializer)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
```

In my case I had an enum `ConnectionType` to specify what derived type the object was.

Connection.cs:

```
    [JsonConverter(typeof(ConnectionJsonConverter))]
    public abstract class Connection : Entity
    {
        #region Properties
        // what type of system are we connecting to? database / api / ldap ...
        public ConnectionType ConnectionType { get; set; }

        // an optional description to explain where the connection is going
        public string Description { get; set; } = "";
        #endregion


        #region Helper Methods
        // test if the connection is good. Will throw an error if the connection is not good.
        public abstract Task Test();
        #endregion
    }
```

LDAPConnection.cs:

```
    public class LDAPConnection : Connection
    {
        #region Properties
        public string Endpoint { get; set; }
        public string? Username { get; set; }
        public string? Password { get; set; }
        #endregion

        #region Helper Methods
        public override async Task Test()
        {
            DirectoryEntry directoryEntry = new DirectoryEntry(this.Endpoint, this.Username, this.Password);

            // check if the native object exists. If it does, then we are connected
            if (directoryEntry.NativeObject == null)
            {
                throw new Exception("Unable to bind to server");
            }

            // assume that if we got here without any exceptions, we are connected.
        }
        #endregion
    }
```

Then you can have one controller for all derived types:

```
// POST: /api/connections/create
[HttpPost, ActionName("Create")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Create([Bind] Connection connection)
{
    connection.Test();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use JsonDerivedType attribute in .NET 7, see [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json/polymorphism?pivots=dotnet-7-0)

```cs
[JsonDerivedType(typeof(WeatherForecastBase), typeDiscriminator: "base")]
[JsonDerivedType(typeof(WeatherForecastWithCity), typeDiscriminator: "withCity")]
public class WeatherForecastBase
{
    public DateTimeOffset Date { get; set; }
    public int TemperatureCelsius { get; set; }
    public string? Summary { get; set; }
}

public class WeatherForecastWithCity : WeatherForecastBase
{
    public string? City { get; set; }
}
```